# UIWebView didFinishLoading fires multiple times

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have some code that needs to run after the a `UIWebView` finishes loading a document.  For that I've set the `UIWebView`'s delegate to my controller, and implemented the `webViewDidFinishLoading` method.

This gets called multiple times, depending on the type of page to load.  I'm not sure if it's because of ajax requests, requests for images, or maybe even iframes.

Is there a way to tell that the main request has finished, meaning the HTML is completely loaded?

Or perhaps delay my code from firing until all of those events are done firing?

Comment: 3 yrs late to the game, but have you found a dependable solution? You have selected an answer, claiming that passed `webView` gives you *actual current request URL* which totally differs from my observation. I do always get the original `[UIWebView loadRequest]` URL, hence no clue what's being started/loaded. I also made [my own summarising post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343516/ios-uiwebview-page-load-observability) with no answer so far.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It could be enlightening (if you haven't gone this far yet) to NSLog a trace of load starts and finishes.

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
       NSLog(@"Loading: %@", [request URL]);
       return YES;
    }


    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
       NSLog(@"didFinish: %@; stillLoading: %@", [[webView request]URL],
            (webView.loading?@"YES":@"NO"));
    }


    - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
       NSLog(@"didFail: %@; stillLoading: %@", [[webView request]URL],
            (webView.loading?@"YES":@"NO"));
    }
```

I just watched the calls to all three in one of my projects which loads a help page from my bundle and contains embedded resources (external css, YUI!, images). The only request that comes through is the initial page load, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` isn't called for any of the dependencies. So it is curious why your didFinishLoad is called multiple times.

Perhaps what you're seeing is due to redirects, or as mentioned, ajax calls within a loaded page. But you at least should be able balance calls to `shouldStartLoad` and either of the other two delegate functions and be able to determine when the loading is finished.

Comment: This ultimately helped me figure it out.  I was using my own webView ivar to determine the request URL, but that never changed.  The webView passed into this method contained the actual current request URL and I could see all of the additional content loading (iframes, etc).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be 

(webView.loading?@"YES":@"NO")

instead of 

(webView.loading?@"NO":@"YES")

Comment: wkw, I've got the same problem. Can you please help me; I just can't figure out the way how'd you 'balance' calls to these delegate functions?

Comment: - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    self.loadBalance--;
    if (self.loadBalance == 0)
     // ACTUAL page finished load
    }
}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    self.loadBalance++;
}

Comment: I'm seeing the page redirects give me two shouldStart calls and one didFinish call. Anybody know how to deal with this?

Comment: Thx @MikeS but you should probably also watch for didFailLoadWithError:

Comment: @VibhorGoyal You are right; I edited the answer. That was clearly confusing.

Comment: very useless answer. I load local html with iframe (from youtube). If I use your example then `webViewDidFinishLoad:` is executer for 1st time and fails for next 2 calls. Do you really think it is a correct behaviour?

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov the answer isn't useless, but it is "dated" now. It was written in 2009. It's important to consider the age of SO posts and comments when evaluating their content. Just saying...

Answer (score 54):

You can do something like this to check when loading is finished. Because you can have a lot of content on the same page you need it.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview  {
    if (webview.isLoading)
        return;
    // do some work
}
```

Comment: ok this sort of worked (and in fact much cleaner than the NSTimer abomination I had previously concocted).

It does unfortunately get to the //do some work section more than once, most likely because there is a delay between requests.

Any ideas on how to ensure that it only gets called once?

Comment: When you say "delay between requests", are you making multiple requests with an NSUrl? You could use the request property of webview if you need to correlate the requests. If you want direct msg me on twitter and we can figure this out then update this post.

Comment: yeah, eventually that if(webview.loading) returns false, and I execute my code (show an alert, say).  The alert box is shown twice, because apparently something else starts loading after the main request is finished... I'm not sure.

Comment: @Ari have you actually seen that any time? For me didStartLoad always gives webView.loading==true and didFinishLoad gives webView.loading==false. I wonder what the flag would be for if the logic was so simple minded.

Answer (score 12):

Check this one it so simply and easy way to achieve no need to write too much code:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
        if ([[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"] isEqualToString:@"complete"]) {
            // UIWebView object has fully loaded.
        }
    }
```

Comment: How would you transfer this to Swift? Since `stringByEvaluatingJavascript(from:)` returns a `String?`, I am testing against `nil`, but it **never fails**. Perhaps I should test against the empty string?

Answer (score 9):

This question is already solved, but I see it lacks an answer that actually explains why multiple calls to `webViewDidFinishLoad` are actually expected behavior

The aforementioned method is called every time the webview finishes loading a frame. From the [UIWebViewDelegate protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

> **webViewDidFinishLoad:**
>   Sent after a web view finishes loading a frame.

In fact, this is also true for all the other methods that comprise the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 7):

Try this it will work fine

```
 -(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview  
    {
       if (webview.isLoading)
           return;
       else
       {
           // Use the code here which ever you need to run after webview loaded 
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the callback method is called every time a frame is done loading. In order to prevent this set the "suppressesIncrementalRendering" property of the webview to true. this will prevent the webview from rendering until the entire data is loaded into the memory. This did the trick for me

Comment: Still kept calling the callbacks even though I set it to true

Answer (score 2):

I have notice something similar and it was a confusion: I have a `UITabBarController`, it seems to preload all `ViewControllers` linked to its tabs on launching the App (in spite of showing just first_Tab_ViewController), so when several tabs have `ViewController` with WebView their respective `webViewDidFinishLoad` are called and if I have copied pasted:

```
NSLog(@"size width %0.0f height %0.0f", fitingSize.width, fittingSize.height);
```

in several, I get several output in console that appears to be a double calling when they really are single calling in two different `UIWebViews`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the loading and request properties in the webViewDidFinishLoad method

Comment: I've checked the Content-Type HTTP header and the URL and they don't give me any useful information.

What information are you suggesting to look at?

Answer (score -1):

Possibly related to this issue is a property on UIWebView introduced in iOS6: `suppressesIncrementalRendering`.

Comment: Hi Joris, perhaps my contribution should have been a comment rather than an answer. Either way, I believe it does directly relate to the question asked.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. See the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617984-suppressesincrementalrendering