# how to connection between two webview on a same sceen

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

how to create a connection between two webview, and also it should communicate. These both webview contains javascript. One thing more how to invoke javascript methods from ojective c(Xcode).

Comment: something is wrong with the grammar please don't mind

Comment: what do you mean by connection do you mean communicating ?

Comment: elaborate your problem tat exactly which events you want to trigger ?

Comment: event is to place text on web veiw, right now i dont have java script, but i will be getting within an hour...

Comment: better way is to check the delegate methods of uiwebview :).

Answer (score 2):

use

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

to receive message from one webview use custom url scheme just like "command:cmd"

and

```
- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;
```

to execute cmd in js format to send msg to another webview

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c this link is also similar.