# Draw route in Apple map in ios 6

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ios6-maps

I want to draw a route between two places. I have the GPS value of those places. I can get the GPS route values between those places from the google api `http://maps.google.com/maps?output=dragdir&saddr=&daddr=`.

I want to know that will google reject my app. Because I found that "`the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited. Additionally, calculation of directions generates copyrights and warnings which must be displayed to the user in some fashion. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions`"

Ple give me clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use the Google Maps API unless you use it with a Google Map. To use the direction data you would have to use a `UIWebView` with a javascript based Google Map.

Comment: So, in ios 6, I can only use UIWebView to display a route in MKMapView, is it?

Comment: It's not that you can't draw a route using the data in an Apple map. It's just that it's against Google's policy. And the map in a UIWebView is not a MKMapView but you would be using the Google Maps javascript API directly.

Comment: If we are using UIWebView for displaying map, then is it possible to access all actions (like annotation clicking, getting touch location of map, add/remove annotation, add/remove overlay etc.) like normal map view?

Comment: It's not as nice and easy as using the `MKMapView` but it should be possible using callbacks from your `UIWebView` to objective-c. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c