# Creating a popover on iPad at a specific location

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller

Let me preface this by saying that I'm a totally noob when it comes to iOS development and have decided to learn by just diving straight in

I've started my app by using the Master-Detail view application template, and have a UIWebView in the DetailView.

I'm looking to display a popover at any arbitrary location in response to an event like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627366/2592), however I'm having trouble doing this. Everything I google either attaches the popup to a button, or does not use storyboards.

I would love some guidance on how I can approach this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below code and make change in CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) to whatever position you like.

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *modalNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
UIPopoverController *popoverControllerTemp = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:modalNavigationController];
self.popoverController = popoverControllerTemp;
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but how do I get to the popoverController part? I've made a popover view in my storyboard http://i.imgur.com/uqwfc.png and attached it to my detail view with popover, but how do I connect that to your code?

Comment: Paramasivan, thanks for your edit, but I'm afraid I will need a little more help, or at least a push in the right direction. Being new to iOS dev, I'm struggling with how to get from what I have now (basic  Master-Detail view application) to what you posted

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a Open Source project you can use [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fwtpopover?utm_source=Cocoa%20Controls&utm_campaign=366a400187-Cocoa_Controls_Weekly_Roundup_2012_09_26&utm_medium=email).