# Catching JavaScript asynchronous calls with Objective-c

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

I catch `javascript` calls with `UIWebViewDelegate`.

It looks like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{      
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[[JSBridgeController alloc] init] js:request];
if (dictionary) {
    if ([dictionary[@"methodName"] isEqualToString:@"gimmeUser"]) {
        [self.delegate gimmeUserJS: dictionary];
    }
    if ([ dictionary[@"methodName"] isEqualToString:@"initMe"]) {
        [self.delegate initMeJS: dictionary];
    }
}
return YES;}
```

The problem is on the web side for me. It has dozens such `JS` requests as in above code and send them asynchronous. So if I get two request same time the webview delegate can see only one of them and ignore the other one.

I tried to use `NSOperationQueue` and `NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest` but without any success.

How could I invoke `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` delegate for each async `JS` request?

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about this would be to generate a unique identifier for your view.
Then, store it in a dictionary with references to your views.  Your views can then pass the identifier back by navigating to "callback:callback?id="+your_passed_id in your JS.

```
if ( [[[inRequest URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"callback"] ) {
    //then use the query string and parse for id 
    //in order to have individual control over callbacks
    NSString *queryString = [[inRequest URL] query];
}
```

for mor info on the callback pattern see: 
[Javascript in UIWebView callback to C/Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c)

I know it's complicated, but it's a solution...
Good luck!