# How to call object c action in javascript function

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, object

is it possible to call an object c action, when you are executing a javascript function. I have this function in java.

```
    .when('/testimonials',    { 
        controller: 'TestiController',      
        templateUrl: 'partials/testimonials.html'
    })
```

And i want to have this action executed when the javascript function is being executed..

```
- (IBAction)knap2:(id)sender{

    knap1.hidden = YES;

}
```

I've tried searching but couldn't find anything.

Comment: See eg here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2873899/javascript-in-uiwebview-callback-to-c-objective-c

Comment: @TheEye, awesome, but can't use it, since it's now a web view.. :)

Comment: Indeed indeed - maybe this helps: https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

Comment: @TheEye i'll try that out later :)