# autoplay youtube video : Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube

I wish to autoplay a youtube video from a specific time using Objective-C.
I used the following:

```
    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];

     NSLog(@"%s",__FUNCTION__);

    appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    float width = 309.0f;
    float height = 196.0f;

    NSString *youTubeURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Gyf1kjaUZCo?autoplay=1";

    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    wv.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
    [html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
    [html appendString:@"body {"];
    [html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
    [html appendString:@"color: white;"];
    [html appendString:@"}"];
    [html appendString:@"</style>"];
    [html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
    [html appendFormat:@"<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Gyf1kjaUZCo?autoplay=1\" allowfullscreen frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>", width, height];
    [html appendString:@"</body></html>"];

    [wv loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

    [self.videoView addSubview:wv];

}
```

But the video doesn't autoplay. Where am I getting wrong? 
How do I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying it on iOS device. It wont work on simulator

Comment: oh no i am trying it on simulator only, I ll check it on device as well.

Comment: tested in device, still not running automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem with auto playing a youtube video,
You can find my solution here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717754/objective-c-how-to-autoplay-a-youtube-video-in-a-uiwebview)

Dont forget to set the `UIWebView` `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` property to NO.

Comment: did that, still the same :(

Comment: did you see the answer in the link?

Comment: thanks it worked! But how do i play the video after a certain time?

Comment: not sure about that, try looking in the YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference

Comment: looking into it, found a method- player.seekTo(time in seconds), but it does not work, see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use it like this-

```
NSString *htmlString =@"<html><head>"
            "<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no, width = 212\"/></head>"
            "<body style=\"background:#FFFFF;margin-left:0px\">"
            "<div><object width=\"309\" height=\"196\">"
            "<param name=\"wmode\" value=\"transparent\"></param>"
            "<embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/Gyf1kjaUZCo?autoplay=1?f=user_favorites&app=youtube_gdata\""
            "type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" wmode=\"transparent\" width=\"309\" height=\"196\"></embed>"
            "</object></div></body></html>";

        [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

However it may need to tap the play button (I don't exactly know if it autoplays) but still it will return the control to the application.