# iOS Force user to watch a YouTube video

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, youtube

Im using this code to play a commercial video in my iOS application:

```
- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString *)urlString frame:(CGRect)frame {

UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[videoView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe width=\"%f\" height=\"%f\" src=%@ frameborder=\"1\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",frame.size.width-10,frame.size.height-10,urlString] baseURL:nil];
[self.view addSubview:videoView];
[videoView release];
}
```

I want to force the user to see the video and close the `UIWebView` once the video is completed without allowing the user to shut the video off.

I think if i can make the Video plays automatically and set the:

```
videoView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

that will force the user to watch it.

**My Questions:**

**1-** How to force the  `UIWebView` using `<iframe>` ?

**2-** How to detect if the video finished playing?

**3-** Is there any other way **(Better One)** to play `YouTube` videos in `iOS`?

Glad to hear any other ideas or answers, Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can detect if the video is finished with JavaScript and the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Comment: Check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14702453/2315974. But forcing the user to watch something is not a good idea and it's a bad practice.

Comment: Don't be surprised when you read 1-star reviews.

Comment: @danypata can u explain why its a bad practice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @danypata at least i want to play it automatically and close it when its done

Comment: There is no user in the world who want to be forced to do something in  to an app, you should provide informations/functionality/data/etc through your app and let the user to decide if he/she wants to view or use what your app provides. If a user want's to watch your youtube video he/she will watch it, if not he/she will close the app and probably will never use it again. If this is your target for the app, you are on the right way to accomplish it, if not, it's better to let the user close the vide if he/she don't want to watch it.

Comment: Thank you @danypata, i will consider this at my app, at least i want to play it automatically and close it when its done,,, any idea??

Comment: Did you check the SO answer posted in the above comment ?

Comment: Yes i did, that solve the finishing of the video, but has no auto play feature, BTW i tried that code before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
videoView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

and you can create a `UIButton` to close the video.

Answer (score -1):

you can use LBYoutube for youtube videos. see following link

[LBYouTube](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lbyoutubeview)

Comment: This example has nothing i asked for, no auto play, can't detect if the video finished playing !!