# How to play video on server on uiwebview in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In my app IOS I must play videos that reside on server. When I call the URL (http://www.example.com/example/?q=courses/9/module/148) from computer's browser it returns file (.flv) and the browser asked me if I have to save or open the file.
How to do to play video in  IOS app'view by URL address?
Is it possible by UIWebView?

Thanks

Comment: Try this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459711/detecting-uiwebview-finish-to-play-youtube-video-on-ipad

Answer (score 0):

First create an String with your html embed code, here is an example:

```
 NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<iframe src=\"http://myvideo.com" width=\"305\" height=\"150\"  frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"> </iframe>"];
```

Then load the address into your web view

```
[self.myWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://whicheveraddresyouwant.com"]];
```