# reloading UIWebView makes it blank

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlconnection

I am loading a webpage in a UIWebView using the following method

```
 [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                    queue:loadingQueue
                        completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                           NSData *data,
                                           NSError *error) {
                            if(!error) {
                                [_webView loadData: data
                                          MIMEType: [response MIMEType]
                                  textEncodingName: [response textEncodingName]
                                           baseURL:nil];
                           }
                       }];
```

Firstly, for a few pages the images are not loaded at all. And secondly, when I refresh a page later by

```
      [_webView reload];
```

The web view turns blank.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

TIA,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few iterations and web searches, I understood that this problem occurs mainly (if not only) because of sites with relative paths.

Expecting that at least the first problem will be solved, I modified the

```
     [_webView loadData: data
               MIMEType: [response MIMEType]
       textEncodingName: [response textEncodingName]
                baseURL: nil];
```

to include the baseURL as

```
                baseURL: [request URL]];
```

Surprisingly BOTH problems were solved. I can understand why it helped solve the "images not downloading" part, but I am unable to guess the reason for why an already (successfully) loaded page would turn blank, if the baseURL is absent.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks,
Nikhil

Answer (score 1):

> I am loading a webpage in a UIWebView using the following method `[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest`

Well, don't. UIWebView already knows how to fetch the data from the Internet, and loads its request asynchronously. So just hand UIWebView the request by calling `loadRequest:`. Now sit back and wait for the delegate messages to arrive. If there's a problem, the delegate messages will tell you.

Comment: my problem is, I am loading multiple UIWebViews and I realized NSURLConnection is the only way to do it like multi-threading would have done. Else my UIWebViews load really slowly (as they all populate the main thread). Any suggestion?

Comment: No, they do not. I just said, it happens asynchronously. That means that UIWebView does its own background threading. It is already multithreaded.

Comment: you are perhaps right. I was distracted by the multiple reloads/flickers in a view and slower delivery with the loadRequest method of UIWebView.

Comment: What is causing the delays and flickering is probably the load on the *network* (multiple simultaneous requests). You can stop the flickering with `suppressesIncrementalRendering` (on iOS 6), but it might be wise to use the delegate methods to load the web views sequentially.

Comment: Alternatively, load the web views before showing them (and use the delegate methods to know when that has happened).

Comment: I was thinking along these lines, unable to guess how one does it with UIWebViews. Could you give me a small snippet of this logic (I meant, first load the UIWebViews completely and then render)

Comment: What I couldn't figure out was, due to those independently loaded iFrames, I considered it impossible to guess when the loading is complete, exactly.

Comment: Hmm. So you're saying `webViewDidFinishLoad:` arrives but it's lying?

Comment: sort of.... the webViewDidStart ... didFailLoadWithError, and ...didFinishLoad cycles for every new iFrame the webpage may initiate via its own js/jQuery. I keep a counter for this. Though it doesn't seem sufficient to decide whether the content is fully loaded or something will start later.

Comment: Didn't know about this. I see that it is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842370/uiwebview-didfinishloading-fires-multiple-times - This is seems like a major shortcoming in the delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the first call of the loadData works well, but next calls load blank pages.

I tried the following workaround and it works:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
[webView loadData:data MIMEType:mimeType textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL new]];
```

Thus a call of the loadRequest fixes the webView's state.