# webViewDidFinishLoad called multiple times for single loadrequest

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have been using webView delegate successfully from long time. But recently I faced strange issue with this delegate. In my current project I am trying to access my router from webview.  I am passing username and password inside URL only. Below is load request code.

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://uname:password@192.168.1.1"]]];
```

This calls webView delegate method (webViewDidFinishLoad and webViewDidStartLoad) 5 times. Is it expected? When I pass simple URL like google.com it works as expected. But with username and password why these delegate methods are called 5 times?

If this behaviour is correct then I need to know why it calls 5 times only. The reason is, in my program - I am calling performSegueWithIdentifier in webViewDidFinishLoad method and in present form it calls segue 5 times. For workaround I can maintain count and will call performSegueWithIdentifier on 5th count only.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842370/uiwebview-didfinishloading-fires-multiple-times

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`webViewDidStartLoad/webViewDidFinishLoad` are called once per HTML frame.  Your content likely has multiple frames in it.

See [UIWebViewDelegate docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webViewDidStartLoad:).

> **webViewDidStartLoad:** 
>   Sent after a web view starts loading a frame.

Comment: Thanks TomSwift. My web page has 4 frames. Here is more info about html frames - http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html

Answer (score 6):

This Methods works for me... :)

```
#pragma mark UI Web View Delegate
NSInteger webViewLoads;
//a web view starts loading
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    webViewLoads++;
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loading..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
}

//web view finishes loading
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    webViewLoads--;
    [self performSelector:@selector(webViewFinishLoadWithCondition) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}

//web view handling error
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    webViewLoads--;
        NSLog(@"Web View Did Fail Load With Error : %@",error);
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}

-(void)webViewFinishLoadWithCondition{
    if(webViewLoads==0){
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
    }
}
```

Comment: This could use some more explanation. How exactly does it solve the problem?

Comment: It gives the option to only do something at the last -webViewDidFinishLoad:

Answer (score 0):

As `webViewDidStartLoad/webViewDidFinishLoad` are called once per HTML frame, Use an integer to find when the last frame load is finished,

In detail :

- Increment the integer in `webViewDidStartLoad`
- Decrement the integer in `webViewDidFinishLoad`
- In `webViewDidFinishLoad` check when integer is zero, Which means all the frames of web page are loaded, Now call the selector

This is an explanation of @marvin's answer

---

---

**Best approach:**

Check for `isLoading` in `webViewDidFinishLoad` and `isLoading` is false, do what ever u want

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview  
{
   if (!webview.isLoading)
   {
       // webview is done loading content.

       // `performSegueWithIdentifier` / Your code Here

   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there is more than one frame - it suceeds multiple times

Comment: please follow the first approach, hope this helps!