# Load a View (and it's WebView object) in the Background and then performing the Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, swift

I have a Navigation controller that manages through a segue two web views. When someone clicks a specific link in the first view controller, the link is opened in the second view controller in another web view. Therefore the user clicks a link, a segue is performed to the next view and the new page is loaded.

I would like for the segue to wait until the webpage in the second view controller has loaded in the background before performing the segue.

I tried to do something like this (as the loadURL request in in the viewDidLoad function) but (as I expected) I get an error (fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None) as the webView has not yet loaded! Anyone knows how to prevent this?

```
//code 
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if(segue.identifier == "second"){         
        segue.destinationViewController.load()
        segue.destinationViewController.viewDidLoad()            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

- create a dummy webview in the first view controller, (a webview not added to the main view).
- in the same first VC, when the user clicks the link, begin `loadRequest` on the dummy webview
- then in `webViewDidFinishLoad` (of first VC) call `performSegue`
- in `prepareForSegue` add the dummy webView to the second view controller main view (using `addSubView`)

I noted that `webViewDidFinishLoad` is [called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842370/uiwebview-didfinishloading-fires-multiple-times) and you have to add some code to really know when the loading is finished (and not to call `prepareForSegue` multiple times).

It's not very simple but hope it helped.

EDIT:

This is a (raw) example of the code, I have tested it and it works, but you have to adjust something (as the dimensions of the view and the *finishLoad* thing) (the action of the button is `openPage`):

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

    var dummyWebViewInFirstVC: UIWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480))
    var done = false

    @IBAction func openPage(sender: AnyObject) {


        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com/")
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        dummyWebViewInFirstVC.loadRequest(request)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        dummyWebViewInFirstVC.delegate = self
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(theWebView: UIWebView) {

        if !done {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openPage", sender: self)
            done = true;
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

        let secondViewController : UIViewController = segue.destinationViewController as UIViewController
        secondViewController.view.addSubview(dummyWebViewInFirstVC)
    }
}
```

Comment: But using   let NextView = secondViewController()
            NextView.secondWebView = tempWebView

Doesn't work.. is there a way of passing a loaded webView to another UIView?

Comment: Use: secondViewController.view.addSubview(dummyWebViewOfFirstVC)

Comment: I get fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None by doing that.. (as the other view is of course not loaded! Is there a way to prevent this?)