# WKWebView webViewDidFinishLoad only called once

Tags: ios, swift, webview, uiwebview, wkwebview

Some specific URL https://stg.express.rakuten.co.jp/?tn=600149999205 when I open the page in WKWebView it's calling didCommitNavigation multiple time (2 times) but it's calling didFinishNavigation delegate method only for one time.

Does anyone have an idea why it's happening?

I referred [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842370/uiwebview-didfinishloading-fires-multiple-times) but in that case, webViewDidStartLoad/webViewDidFinishLoad called multiple time for a single request while in my case it's calling didCommitNavigation multiple times.

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
}

open func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
}
```

Comment: can you share your codes ?

Comment: @zeytin sorry method name are didCommitNavigation/didFinishNavigation I updated my question.

Comment: seems to get called whenever a frame loads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15594800/4833705